# Unable to use user-defined operator in Prolog

Tags: prolog, operators, user-defined

I've been stuck for quite some time on this issue, my Prolog program has the following line within its operator definitions:

```
:- op(100, xfx, [has,gives,'does not',eats,lays,isa]).
```

and then this fact:

```
fact :: X isa animal :-
     member(X, [cheetah,tiger,giraffe,zebra,ostrich,penguin, albatross]).
```

When I try to use the operator It says it is undefined and I just do not understand why.

```
?- peter isa tiger.
ERROR: [Thread pdt_console_client_0_Default Process] toplevel: Undefined  
procedure: (isa)/2 (DWIM could not correct goal)
```

Sorry if its something silly (which it probably is) but I am new to Prolog. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: It works exactly as expected if you just remove `fact ::`. To define a rule in Prolog, use `Head :- Body.`, for example: `X isa animal :- member(...).`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It **is** working. See for yourself:

```
    stefan@stefan-Lenovo-G510 ~ $ swipl
    Welcome to SWI-Prolog (Multi-threaded, 64 bits, Version 7.3.12)
    % ...

    ?- op(100, xfx, [has,gives,'does not',eats,lays,isa]).
    true.

    ?- Term = (peter isa tiger).
    Term = peter isa tiger.
```

The error message that you got ...

```
    procedure: (isa)/2 (DWIM could not correct goal)
```

... says that too!

Is it clearer now?

Comment: Oh okay so you have to store it in a variable for it to work? I am trying to develop an expert system that begins to ask questions after I state that peter isa tiger so I'm not sure how I can make that work without the 'Term =' preceding it.

Comment: It works without `Term = ...` if you have a predicate `(isa)/2`. You can add to that definition on the [tag:prolog-toplevel] like this: `?- assert(peter isa tiger).`
**Then** you can ask `?- peter isa X.`. Let's add one more: `?- assert(peter isa male).` And ask again: `?- peter isa Y.` I get the answer `X = tiger ; X = male`.

Comment: Okay this is making much more sense to me, although I am trying to make the commands somewhat user-friendly so is there a way I can make `peter isa tiger` work without assert() as well?

Comment: Directly in the [tag:prolog-toplevel]? No. `X isa Y` **is** a valid goal to ask. To tell, use [tag:prolog-assert].

Comment: @user2023740. If you're aiming at implementing an expert system, designing and implementing the REPL / toplevel / shell is important and should be tailored to the concrete use-cases you have in mind.